# String padding for a text template

Tags: php

I'm creating a PDF file from a txt-template with tcpdf ([Example 8][1]). The txt-template looks like this:

```
SALUTATION  
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME                            
STREET                     CURRENTDATE
SOMEMOREINFORMATION                           MYWEBSITE
```

I replace those markers with the correct value. So that it would look like this:

```
Mr.  
John Doe                   
Downingstreet 10           14th May, 2010
john@doe.com                                  www.stackoverflow.com
```

In this example, when I replace the values, the indention of the date is dependent on the length of the street name (which I don't want). I could solve this issue with str_pad but the problem is, I normally use three columns and there are lines which only have content in col1 and col3 as in the last line. How can I solve that problem? Is there something like the "overwrite" function in Word, that when you write, the text just gets overwritten?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count street's string length and then add/remove left padding of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sprintf](http://docs.php.net/sprintf), e.g.

```
function something($street, $currentDate, $foo) {
  $s = sprintf('%-20s    %-18s    %s',
    $street, 
    $currentDate, 
    $foo
  );
  return $s;
}

echo something('streetA', '14th May, 2010', 'lalala'), "\n";
echo something('Downingstreet 10', '14th May, 2010', 'lalala'), "\n";
echo something('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 10', '14th May, 2010', 'lalala'), "\n";
```

prints

```
streetA                 14th May, 2010        lalala
Downingstreet 10        14th May, 2010        lalala
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 10    14th May, 2010        lalala
```

(as you can see from the third line the width specification is the *minimum length*, so you might have to use something like [substr()](http://docs.php.net/substr))

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are just str_replace()'ing the placeholders with their values?

```
$streetPlaceHolder = 'STREET                     ';
$streetReplacement = str_pad('Downingstreet 10', strlen($streetPlaceHolder));
$template = str_replace($streetPlaceHolder, $streetReplacement, $template);
```

Presumably you will run into the same problem with SOMEMOREINFORMATION. This same solution can be used.

I realize you said str_pad was not an ideal solution for you. However, I do not understand why, even if you extend this to three columns. You can still get by with this method.